# Not able to call returned method from instance name

Tags: javascript

In the below code, I'm not able to call `job1` & `job2` which is being returned by `jobContainer`.

```
// Code goes here

var jobContainer = function() {

  var count = 0;

  var task1 = function() {
    count += 1;
    console.log("inside task1 " + count);
  };

  var task2 = function() {
    count += 1;
    console.log("inside task2 " + count);
  };

  return {
    job1: task1(),
    job2: task2()
  };

};

var tasker = jobContainer();
tasker.job1 // not working
tasker.job2 // not working
tasker.job2 // not working
```

Output:

```
inside task1 1
inside task2 2
```

Thank You

Comment: `return {
    job1: task1,
    job2: task2
  };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
    job1: task1(),
    job2: task2()
};
```

The problem is, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you're calling the functions *before* the return object is constructed. I'm guessing your intent was to return the functions themselves, not the return values.

Change the above code to (note the functions aren't being called):

```
return {
    job1: task1,
    job2: task2
  };
```

Then change the second bit to:

```
var tasker = jobContainer();
tasker.job1()
tasker.job2()
tasker.job2()
```

Note we're calling the functions now.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect returns are made

```js
// Code goes here
var jobContainer = function() {
  var count = 0;

  var task1 = function() {
    count += 1;
    console.log("inside task1 " + count);
  };

  var task2 = function() {
    count += 1;
    console.log("inside task2 " + count);
  };

  return {
    job1: task1,
    job2: task2
  };

};

var tasker = jobContainer();
tasker.job1()  
tasker.job2() 
tasker.job2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return result of execution `task1` and `task2` instead of functions, so replace:

```
return {
  job1: task1(),
  job2: task2()
};
```

to

```
return {
  job1: task1,
  job2: task2
};
var tasker = jobContainer();
tasker.job1() // inside task1 1
tasker.job2() // inside task2 2
tasker.job2() // inside task2 3
```

**Good Luck !**